# I have got Query How can convert query to dsl

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I have got Query How can convert query to dsl,I don't know how to convert,Can you help me
thanks

```golang
centroidQuery := elastic.NewBoolQuery().
  Must(elastic.NewMatchQuery("centroid.bid.keyword", bid)).
  Must(elastic.NewRangeQuery("centroid.count_user").Gte(2)).
  MustNot(elastic.NewMatchQuery("centroid.source", "live")).
  MustNot(elastic.NewQueryStringQuery("deleted:true"))

queryCountAggs := elastic.NewSumAggregation().Field("centroid.count")

queryCentroidResult, err := IntersectionClient.Client.
  Search(queryCentroidIndex).
  Query(centroidQuery).
  Sort("centroid.count_user", false).
  From(int((pageNum-1)*pageSize)).
  Size(int(pageSize)).
  Aggregation("queryCount", queryCountAggs).
  Do(context.Background())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/olivere/elastic"
)

func main() {
    centroidQuery := elastic.NewBoolQuery().
        Must(elastic.NewMatchQuery("centroid.bid.keyword", "1")).
        Must(elastic.NewRangeQuery("centroid.count_user").Gte(2)).
        MustNot(elastic.NewMatchQuery("centroid.source", "live")).
        MustNot(elastic.NewQueryStringQuery("deleted:true"))

    queryCountAggs := elastic.NewSumAggregation().Field("centroid.count")


    query := elastic.NewSearchRequest().Index("test").
        Query(centroidQuery).
        Sort("centroid.count_user", false).
        From(0).
        Size(1).
        Aggregation("queryCount", queryCountAggs)

    s,_ := query.Body()
    
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

Output:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "queryCount": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "centroid.count"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "centroid.bid.keyword": {
              "query": "1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "centroid.count_user": {
              "from": 2,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "to": null
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "centroid.source": {
              "query": "live"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "deleted:true"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "centroid.count_user": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to solve the problem